# How can I change the order of the list items in the activity via menu?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**Summary:** I do have a trivial application (demo/prototype) with the activity that displays a list of items (here customers). The items are retreived from the application SQLite database. I am using the `ContentProvider` approach with `LoaderManager` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I need to convert menu-item selection by a user to the selected way of sorting the list. What is the usual way do that? How that user selection should be saved for future? (I am a beginner concerning the Android programming.)

**Details:** In my activity `onCreate` method, the `fillData` method (see the code below, learned from the tutorial) is called to populate the list. It calls the `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`, and that in turn causes calling the `onCreateLoader` that returns the `CursorLoader` instance. The cursor loader uses the content provider and passes also the argument that defines sorting. So far, I am using a fixed argument for sorting the list. My guess is that I should call the `fillData();` when processing the menu item click. It should cause creating another loader and another adapter. But how the information should be passed to the `onCreateLoader`?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.insert_customer:   // this already works for me
        createCustomer();
        return true;

    case R.id.customers_orderby_name_asc:
        ???                      // What should be here?
        fillData();              // I should probably call this.
        return true:

    case R.id.customers_orderby_name_desc:
        ???
        fillData();
        return true:
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
...
private void fillData() {
    String[] from = new String[] { CustomerTable.COLUMN_CODE,
                                   CustomerTable.COLUMN_NAME,
                                   CustomerTable.COLUMN_TOWN,
                                   CustomerTable.COLUMN_STREET};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.code, R.id.name, R.id.town, R.id.street };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.customer_row, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

// After initLoader()...
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { CustomerTable.COLUMN_ID,
                            CustomerTable.COLUMN_CODE,
                            CustomerTable.COLUMN_NAME,
                            CustomerTable.COLUMN_STREET,
                            CustomerTable.COLUMN_TOWN };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            DemoContentProvider.CUSTOMERS_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
            CustomerTable.COLUMN_NAME);  // here fixed order by the column
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a local variable within your activity.

The column name can be written in SharedPrefs for later use (or for immediate use as well).

If you move your `LoaderCallbacks` to a class outside your activity, you can make it a field of the `LoaderCallbacks` implementation, and pass it in the constructor or in a setter.

Comment: +1 for the SharedPreferences -- this is what I wanted but I did not know :) Is there any advantage to move `LoaderCallbacks` outside the activity? So far, I am using `public class CustomersOverviewActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` and it works fine even with the private variable.

Comment: if your LoaderCallbacks does a lot of things, and if you want to make a clear separation, yes, it makes sense to put it outside your activity.

Answer (score 1):

this CustomerTable.COLUMN_NAME means the ordering, right? So create several methods with only change in this place like

Create a method which will get the sorting column as parameter:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args, String orderByColumn)
...
     CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                DemoContentProvider.CUSTOMERS_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
                orderByColumn == null ? CustomerTable.COLUMN_NAME : orderByColumn);
```

or use some class's field like

```
...
private String orderByColumn;
...
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
    ...
         CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                    DemoContentProvider.CUSTOMERS_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
                    orderByColumn == null ? CustomerTable.COLUMN_NAME : orderByColumn);
```